# Finding solutions of $Ax(t)= x'(t)$ by linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a system of $n$ first-order homogenous differential equations with real coefficients. We can write solutions in vector form: $Ax(t)= x'(t)$ where $A$ is the $n \times n$ coefficient matrix.

Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with $\dim E_\lambda =1$ and the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ equal to $2$.

Let's guess that $y(t) =te^{\lambda t}u +e^{\lambda t}v$ is a solution to the system. I am asked to show that $u$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$ and that $v$ satisfies $(A-\lambda I)v=u$. Then I am asked to show that it's possible to solve for $v$.

I know that $\dim G_\lambda =2$, where $G_\lambda$ is the generalized eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$.

But I really have no idea how to proceed. (Even the wording of the problem confuses me.) I would appreciate some help understanding how to prove what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Continue with your guess $y(t) = te^{\lambda t}u + e^{\lambda t} v$, then we know for it to be a solution it must satisfy $\dot{y}(t) = Ay(t)$. Plugging our expression for $y(t)$ in gives: $\lambda e^{\lambda t}v+e^{\lambda t}u + \lambda t e^{\lambda t}u = Ate^{\lambda t}u + Ae^{\lambda t} v$. Rearrange some terms and the trick will become clear:
\begin{align}
&e^{\lambda t}(\lambda v + u) = e^{\lambda t} (Av) \iff (A-\lambda I)v=u\\
&te^{\lambda t}(Au) = te^{\lambda t}(\lambda u) \iff Au = \lambda u
\end{align}
We end up with our desired eigenvector $u$ and a generalized eigenvector $v$.

Comment: I see that $v$ is a generalized eigenvector. Specifically, $v\in \ker (A-\lambda I)^2$. But how exactly does this imply that we can always solve for $v$? I think it has something to do with the fact that $\dim \ker(A-\lambda I)^2= \dim G_\lambda =2$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I can now see that $v$ is linearly independent of $u$. How do we use this fact to solve for $v$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $y(t) = te^{\lambda t}u + e^{\lambda t}v$ is a solution of $y^\prime(t) = Ay(t)$. Since
$$
 y^\prime(t) = e^{\lambda t}u + t\lambda e^{\lambda t}u + \lambda e^{\lambda t}v = (1+t\lambda)e^{\lambda t}u + \lambda e^{\lambda t}v,
$$
it follows that
$$
 (1+t\lambda)e^{\lambda t}u + \lambda e^{\lambda t}v = te^{\lambda t}Au + e^{\lambda t}Av
$$
for all $t$, and hence, by dividing by $e^{\lambda t}$, which is never $0$ for real $t$, and collecting powers of $t$, you get that
$$
(u+\lambda v - Av) + t(\lambda u-Au) = 0
$$
for all $t$, which, if you like, is an equality of vector-valued functions of $t$.

1. What do you learn by setting $t = 0$ in the above equation?
2. What do you learn by differentiating both sides with respect to $t$ in the above equation?
3. Going back to the expression $y(t) = te^{\lambda t}u + e^{\lambda t}v$, what happens if you plug in $t = 0$? In particular, can you solve for $v$ in terms of the initial value $y(0)$?

Comment: When I set $t=0$, then we see that $(A-\lambda I)v=u$, as desired. That is, we know $u+\lambda v-Av=0$, right? So we can then set $t=1$ to get $Au=\lambda u$. Alternatively, we can differentiate both sides to see that $u$ is an eigenvector. I still don't see how your third hint tells us that we can always solve for $y$. In particular, how can we use the fact that the dimension of $G_\lambda =2$, the algebraic multiplicity  of $\lambda$?

Comment: In an initial value problem, $y(0)$ is a known input, so let $y_0 := y(0)$, whatever it's supposed to be. But then, $y_0 = y(0) = 0 e^{\lambda 0} u + e^{\lambda 0} v = \dotsc$, so can you solve for $v$ in terms of $y_0$? As a result, can you write a formula for $y(t)$ in terms of only $y_0$, $A$, $\lambda$, and $t$? Moreover, what condition on the initial value $y_0$ has been lurking in the background all this time, in order for your guess at a solution to actually be correct?

Comment: So we get $y_0=v$. So of course we can then write $y(t)$ in only those terms. But it this what it means to solve for $v$? Also, I'm guessing, but would the condition lurking in the background  be the linear independence of $\{u, v\}$? If so, how? I really would like to know how the fact that  $v$ is linearly independent of $u$ is relevant.